# Unable to create a proxy in Nuxt 3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I want to create a proxy in Nuxt3 so that /api -> http://my.other.app/api to avoid CORS issues and directly exposing the endpoint.

I have tried everything I can find and I can't seem to create a proxy in Nuxt3, in Nuxt 2 this was very simple, but in Nuxt 3 nothing seems to work.

I have tried using `routeRules`:

https://nitro.unjs.io/config#routerules

and this has no effect at all.

I have also tried using nuxt-proxy (https://github.com/wobsoriano/nuxt-proxy)

This works, but it always proxies everything from the root of my application, the pathFilter option seems to be ignored. I found a [closed issue](https://github.com/wobsoriano/nuxt-proxy/issues/26) that had the same problem, but was resolved by using a different package, which isn't suitable for what I need.

Comment: Have you tried Nitro's proxyRequest ?